# Can't cargo update git dependence?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

I'm trying to update the a git dependency over [here](https://github.com/enigmampc/secret-toolkit/tree/master/packages) to my project. My project have older version of this master branch but now I want to update the dependencies. I run these commands

```
cargo update
cargo build
cargo wasm
```

But nothing happens..The new "`INCUBATOR`" package that I want to add to the project doesn't shows up on the `CARGO.LOCK`

Comment: Please include the relevant dependencies in your `Cargo.toml`

Comment: Maybe try `cargo update --aggressive`? You can also specify the package to update explicitly like `cargo update -p <package>`.